# Suitability of entrySet() for a self-defined class that implements Map.Entry in Java

Tags: java, class, data-structures

Thing were going along smooth enough, until I tried to log my data-structure to the console, at which time I was greeted by this ugly beast:

```
OpcodeCount.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
              for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                                                         ^
  symbol:   method entrySet()
  location: variable map of type Entry<String,Integer>
1 error
```

The data I'm working with, it looks (*more or less*) like this:

```
group 1: makePush
group 2:            
group 3: 2722
group 1: makePush
group 2:            
group 3: 495
group 1: makePush
group 2:            
group 3: 495
group 1: opAdd
group 2:            
group 3: 10756
group 1: opAdd
group 2:            
group 3: 361
```

However, that's not sufficient for my purposes, I need it to look more like this, essentially a list of tuples:

```
{ 
  <makePush, 2722>,
  <makePush, 495>,
  <makePush, 495>,
  <opAdd, 10756>,
  <opAdd, 361>
}
```

After trying different variations of Maps, ArrayLists, Pairs, etc, I finally settled on this construct:

```
final static class MyEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public MyEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
   }

}
```

It gets instantiated in the code here:

```
// output data struct
ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> pairList= new ArrayList<>();
```

Populated like so:

```
//Entry<String,Integer> pair1 = new SimpleEntry<>(groupOne, groupThree);
Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair1 = new MyEntry<String, Integer>(groupOne, Integer.valueOf(groupThree));
//Entry<String,Integer> pair1=new Entry<>(groupOne, groupThree);
pairList.add(pair1);
```

Now, everything was proceeding along smoothly enough until I had to print, this is how I tried to print it:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = pairList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> map = it.next(); //so here you don't need a potentially unsafe cast
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Once again the error, I was hit with this error:

```
OpcodeCount.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
              for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                                                         ^
  symbol:   method entrySet()
  location: variable map of type Entry<String,Integer>
1 error
```

Should I try to implement `entrySet()` as part of that self-defined class? How to do that?

Is the data accessible to be printed in some other way? If so- how?

If you're interested, the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/c3850245593a8219a9ef12b33bb1abb9)- admittedly very hacky- it's just a prototype.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to iterate over a single entry? And why is it called `map`?

Comment: Btw you don't need to implement your own `Entry`. Just use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: @shmosel not sure what you mean by use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`, can you maybe show me an example?

Comment: `Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair1 = new SimpleEntry<>(groupOne, Integer.valueOf(groupThree));`

Comment: how do I declare it? -man- I'm pretty sure I tried that before and it didn't work- I need to know how to instantiate it, populate it, and also print it- otherwise it's like- not so useful- you know what I mean?

Comment: How do you declare what?

Comment: how to declare, instatiate, that data-structure? `Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair1 = new SimpleEntry<>(groupOne, Integer.valueOf(groupThree));` -but- if you look at that gist- I was trying that before

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: I want to use the data-structure you suggest- but you didn't give me the whole story- it comes in three parts- first I need to set it up, then I need to put stuff in it- then I need to access that stuff- you only showed me the part where I put stuff in it

Comment: like this I guess? `Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry =
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("exmpleString", 42);`

Comment: All I was doing was suggesting a replacement for `MyEntry`. The rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've correctly declared `map` as `Map.Entry`. As you saw when you implemented the `Map.Entry` interface, it doesn't have an `entrySet()` method. That's defined on `Map`, but simply naming your entry `map` doesn't confer the `Map` interface on that object, and it's not relevant anyway.

There's no need to call `entrySet()`; your `pairList` is effectively the entry set. Just iterate over that:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
pairList.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("x", 0));
...
pairList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: how would I do that last part, i.e. `pairList.forEach(System.out::println);` with this `LOG.warn(element)`, I can't use `println` as this is part of a Hadoop job?

Comment: cool- perfect answer- thank you very much- finally I printed it like this `for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : pairList) {
    String ki = entry.getKey().toString();
    Integer vi = entry.getValue();
    LOG.warn("key, " + ki + " value " + vi);
}`